# aws batch: get overview over past submitted jobs

Tags: aws-batch

Is there an easy way to list past jobs for a certain queue, ideally on the console?

I lack a view in the web console where I see the past jobs regardless of status

Answer (score 2):

the aws cli also offers to only view one status at a time. Looping over the relevant statuses and making the output pretty using `jq` results in this kind of script:

```
for STATUS in RUNNABLE STARTING RUNNING SUCCEEDED FAILED; do
  echo $STATUS;
  aws batch list-jobs --job-queue cheap-lane --job-status $STATUS |
    jq -r 'def lpad($len; $fill): tostring | ($len - length) as $l | ($fill * $l)[:$l] + .;
           .jobSummaryList[] | [(.createdAt / 1000 | strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")), (.jobName[:25] | lpad(25;" ")), .jobId]|@tsv' |
    sort -r
done
```

The ouptut of the command above is something like:

```
RUNNABLE
STARTING
RUNNING
SUCCEEDED
2020-02-19 11:00                   tutti-loremips       0fc36af9[…]f22
2020-02-19 08:00                   tutti-loremips       7628d413[…]306
2020-02-19 07:38               tutti-loremips-cli       a2c40a72[…]b4a
2020-02-19 05:17        megajob-lister-id-asdfghi       eb5bd15e[…]d5f
2020-02-19 04:14                check-harker-test       b30d0c54[…]c47
2020-02-18 15:22               tutti-loremips-cli       a27b0742[…]096
2020-02-18 14:06               tutti-loremips-cli       86e6a89c[…]eb7
2020-02-18 07:01           tutti-loremips-manual3       8c81afe3[…]2ec
2020-02-18 05:17        megajob-lister-id-asdfghi       1a55d717[…]fbd
FAILED
2020-02-19 07:35               tutti-loremips-cli       76291571[…]5f8
2020-02-19 07:30               tutti-loremips-cli       83563bb6[…]fb3
2020-02-19 07:28               tutti-loremips-cli       dc35b9bb[…]05c
2020-02-18 06:30        tutti-loremips-manual-sub       955a1d0b[…]685
```

btw: there's currently [a PR open for jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/pull/2060) which would make `lpad` available in jq natively.